# Python - Fork a piped command to background and leave it there

Tags: python, background, pipe, fork

I'm new to python, still learning
What i need to do is to fork a complex command to background and continue th execution of my main program, something like this:
I do this from the linux command line (and works ok)

```
./pgm1 arg1 arg2 arg3 | ./pgm22 arg21 arg22 arg23 arg24 &
```

so the program goes to background and i can coninue my work.

How can i run the above command in my python program?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can PIPE the output of the first command to the second using [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

```
from subprocess import PIPE,Popen

p = Popen(["./pgm1" ,"arg1" ,"arg2" ,"arg3" ],stdout=PIPE)
p1 = Popen( ["./pgm22", "arg21", "arg22", "arg23" ,"arg24"],stdin=p.stdout,stdout=PIPE)
p.stdout.close()
```

Popen does not wait for the command to finish.

Comment: "&" is not required here